# jQuery autocomplete suggests all options regardless of input entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a jQuery script that will get a JSON response and create as many "player" objects as there are in the response.

It will then add to `availablePlayers` which I then use as the variable for the `source:` field of `autocomplete`

When a user selects a player name and clicks the "add" button it will, at the moment, just display the `guid` and `name` of a player.

However, no matter what letters I type, all the players are given as an option. To illustrate this, if I type "Z" and none of the players have Z in their name, they options are still displayed.

How can I refine this functionality?

**HTML**

```
<div class="player-widget">
    <label for "players">Players</label>
    <input id="player" />
    <input id="playerGUID" hidden />
    <button id="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var availablePlayers = []; // BLANK ARRAY OF PLAYERS

$("#player").autocomplete({
    source: availablePlayers,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        ui.content = $.map(ui.content, function(value, key) {
            return {
                label: value.name,
                value: value.guid
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#player").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#player").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#playerGUID").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        return false;
    }
});

$.getJSON("http://localhost/Websites/Player-Widgets/service.php", function(data) {

    var feedHTML = '';
    // LOOP THROUGH EACH PLAYER
    $.each(data.players, function(i, player) {

        // DEFINE VARIABLES - BASED ON PLAYER ATTRIBUTES
        var guid = player.guid;
        var name = player.name;
        var dob = player.date_of_birth;
        var birth = player.birthplace;
        var height = player.height;
        var weight = player.weight;
        var position = player.position;
        var honours = player.honours;

        // CREATE NEW PLAYER (OBJECT)
        var player = {
            guid: guid,
            name: name,
            position: position
        };

        // ADD TO PLAYER TAG ARRAY
        availablePlayers.push(player);
    });

    console.log("User friendly array");
    $.each(availablePlayers, function(i, val) {
        console.log(val.guid + " - " + val.name + " [" + val.position + "]");
    });

    console.log("Array printout");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(availablePlayers));

}).done(function(){
    console.log("Done! Success!");
    $("#player").autocomplete("option", "source", availablePlayers);
});

$("#add").click(function() {
    alert($("#playerGUID").val() + " - " + $("#player").val());
});

});
```

**Sample JSON response**

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "guid": "1",
        "name": "Matias Aguero",
        "date_of_birth": "1981-02-13",
        "birthplace": "San Nicolas, Argentina",
        "height": "1.83m (6' 0\")",
        "weight": "109kg (17st 2lb)",
        "position": "Prop",
        "honours": "40 caps"
    },
    {
        "guid": "2",
        "name": "George Catchpole",
        "date_of_birth": "1994-02-22",
        "birthplace": "Norwich, England",
        "height": "1.85em (6ft 1\")",
        "weight": "104kg (16st 5lb)",
        "position": "Centre",
        "honours": ""
    }
]
}
```

Comment: @RegisPortalez what do you mean by this friend?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the source function.
Source function uses request to pass term param to query, and you are ignoring it.
If you're using availablePlayers to query, you should use

```
source: availablePlayers
```

and your current function to map {label, text} object in response parameter.

```
response: function (event, ui) {
        ui.content = $.map(ui.content, function(value, key) {
            return {
                label: value.name,
                value: value.guid
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my code above based on your suggestions but now no names are shown at all. Have I coded it correctly?

Comment: yes, is correct, but your $.get is not populating availablePlayers before you pass it in source param, try to create autocomplete first and update `$().autocomplete("option", "source", availablePlayers)` in $.get success function

Comment: I have added in your suggestions, creating the `autocomplete` first and then updating the source on `done()` but still no success. I have updated the code again, could you confirm its right?

Array printout is - `[{"guid":"1","name":"Matias Aguero","position":"Prop"},{"guid":"2","name":"George Catchpole","position":"Centre"},{"guid":"3","name":"Logovi'i Mulipola","position":"Prop"}]`